# Prestashop redirects me to install/

Tags: prestashop

I have set up prestashop CMS and remove install directory, but when I try to open my site link www.mydomain.com, I have redirected to www.mydomain.com/install/ and CMS says, that page not found (404).

But if I open www.mydomain.com/index.php all works fine!

Why CMS not redirect me from www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/index.php automatically?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but when I set up a Prestashop on local environment I need to restart Apache once the install is done to avoid this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i dont know what may be causing this issue, but Please do the following steps. One may fix your issue.

1) Clear your Browser cache. 
2) Go to Preferences -> SEO & Urls at PS admin. Down the page, you will have some three options

a) Friendly URL

b) Automatically redirect to Canonical URL

c)  Disable apache multiviews

Enable / disable them alternatively and try to load the page.

Also after you enable / disable these features it will be good if you clear your browser cache before loading front page.

Some times i myself get such issues and i fix them like these and it works for me, still i dont know why this issue occures :P

Hope this will help. And if it does not work, let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me but my problem was that it was redirecting to install guide page

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an incorrect rule got created in your htaccess file. (It's in the root folder)

Open htaccess file (keep a copy of it on your desktop) and the code within # Dispatcher should look like below:

```
# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Just check and let me know.